# Typeclass and List

Tags: scala

I have a trait like this:

```
trait ToJSON[T] {
    def toJSON(o: T): JValue
}
```

Any idea how I can extend this for a list of types that implement this trait?

I tried something like this:

```
object ToJSON {
    implicit object StringToJSON extends ToJSON[String] {
        def toJSON(s: String): JValue = {
            JString(s)
        }
    }
    implicit object ListToJSON extends ToJSON[List[ToJSON[_]]] {
        def toJSON[T:ToJSON](l: List[T])(implicit ev: ToJSON[T]): JValue = {
            JArray(l.map(implicitly[ToJSON[T]].toJSON(_)))
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
[error]  both value ev of type apiserver.ToJSON[T]
[error]  and value evidence$1 of type apiserver.ToJSON[T]
[error]  match expected type apiserver.ToJSON[T]
[error]             JArray(l.map(implicitly[ToJSON[T]].toJSON(_)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, that in `ListToJSON` you can't have a method with signature `def toJSON[T:ToJSON](l: List[T])(implicit ev: ToJSON[T])`. The signature has to be `def toJSON(o: T): JValue` to override the method from `ToJSON`.

But you have to provide that `implicit ev: ToJSON[T]` somewhere. This means, that `ListToJSON` shouldn't be an `object`, but a function, that returns a `ToJSON` object.

Here are a few equivalent definitions for that `ListToJSON` function:

```
implicit def ListToJSON[E](implicit ev: ToJSON[E]): ToJSON[List[E]] =
  new ToJSON[List[E]] {
    def toJSON(l: List[E]): JValue = JArray(l.map(ev.toJSON))
  }

// Using automatic conversion of anonymous functions
// to functional interfaces from Scala 2.12
implicit def ListToJSON[E](implicit ev: ToJSON[E]): ToJSON[List[E]] = 
  l => JArray(l.map(ev.toJSON))

// An implicit parameter is an equivalent of a context bound,
// so you can use one or the other.
implicit def ListToJSON[E : ToJSON]: ToJSON[List[E]] = 
  l => JArray(l.map(implicitly[ToJSON[E]].toJSON(_)))
```

Comment: I know we are not supposed to use comments for thanking, but wow! Thanks. You blew my mind :D